# ios:Application got stretched

Tags: ios, iphone-6-plus

I have a legacy code in which autolayout is not used perhaps autoresize mask is used, but whats strange is that even navigation bars look stretched when I deployed that app to iPhone 6+. I have to modernize this app so that navigation bar stays 44pts in all  device families, new keyboard appears etc.

Please suggest me ways to do the same.

Thanks
Ankit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as first step, add the right default.png. (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html)

==> That shows iOS you support the new screen size of iphone 6 / 6+

THEN

it dependents on your app. If you used fixed pixel values based on the old 'default' screen width. you'll have to make it all dynamic

if everything IS already dynamic, you're good

THEN (optional but recommended)

use the new @3x size for all your assets so they don't look blurry

Answer (score 0):

Add a default.png for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html